# how to bind dictionary result to class object c# linq

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

```
   Dictionary<Guid, string> flexEventTriggers = RepositoryContainer.GBM.Flex.Admin_FlexTriggerEvents.AsQueryable()
               .Where(x => flexEventTriggerIds.Contains(x.RecordID)).ToDictionary(x => x.RecordID, x => x.Name);
            Dictionary<Guid, string> lookupEntities = RepositoryContainer.GBM.Flex.Admin_LookupEntities.AsQueryable()
                           .Where(x => lookupEnityIds.Contains(x.RecordID)).ToDictionary(x => x.RecordID, x => x.Name);
            Dictionary<Guid, string> documents = RepositoryContainer.IDB.Flex.Documents.AsQueryable()
                           .Where(x => DocumentRecordIds.Contains(x.RecordID)).ToDictionary(x => x.RecordID, x => x.Name);




            foreach (var log in flexEventTriggerLogsList)
            {
                if (DocumentRecordIds.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var dcoumentId in DocumentRecordIds)
                    {
                        //Fetch DocumentId's, LookupEntity_RecordID,  FlexEventTrigger_RecordID from log additional data
                        flexEventTriggerLogs.Add(new FlexEventTriggerLog
                        {
                            Name = documents[documentId],
                            Event_Name = flexEventTriggers[FlexTriggerEventRecordID],
                            Action_Name = lookupEntities[Entity_RecordID],
                        });

                    }
                }
```

How will I assign data to my object in foreach loop for Name, Event_Name, Action_Name. Currently it is giving error in below code.

```
                        Name = documents[documentId],
                        Event_Name = flexEventTriggers[FlexTriggerEventRecordID],
                        Action_Name = lookupEntities[Entity_RecordID],
```

Comment: So, what's the error details?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your `DocumentRecordIds` is type of `List<Guid>` and the property(`Name, Event_Name, Action_Name`) should be type of `string`.

You could also try this:

```
Name = documents.Where(p => p.Key == dcoumentId).Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```